# Recursively clone a type with non-object values as strings

Tags: typescript

Say I have this type:

```
{
  a: number;
  b?: string;
  c: null | {
    a1: boolean;
    a2: {
      b1: number;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a type out of it that has the exact same structure, but all values (or, leaves) are replaced with strings, like this:

```
{
  a: string;
  b?: string;
  c: null | {
    a1: string;
    a2: {
      b1: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this even possible?
Also, is it possible to create a partial type of it, in which not all keys are required (I know `Partial` exists).

Comment: Sounds like something you can use generics for. Is it possible to just solve it like that?

Comment: I figured as much, but I can't quite get it done.

Comment: Actually, I misread your type. I thought your initial one only had `number` for every value. Sorry, I don't think generics are the way here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of conditional and recursive types:

```
type Stringify<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends object | null ? Stringify<T[key]> : string }
```

In use:

```
interface Thing {
  a: number;
  b?: string;
  c: null | {
    a1: boolean;
    a2: {
      b1: number;
    }
  }
}

const t: Stringify<Thing> = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: {
    a1: "baz",
    a2: {
      b1: "qux",
    },
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgc0QMxAHgCoD4oBeKAbygG0BrCEKFKGkAewylwF0Aud62jqBAAewCMgAmAZyjMARgCsIAY2BQAPlGQBXADY6oAflgIU6LHj4gOhHpJNooAXwBQzlKPgYAhkui4AFqZkzlBQXjzaALayEPAA3CFQsga29qgJoUoRuvoapImhXgCMPLLMzDoQXsgZoWEATDz5dXWyJZpa0bG1oS69zi7OSszIdlDAPHBIaJg4AaaEJM1hPABEGOWrADSJsmuyXvDbiVnBLcX7XgBex+eNZy1J7asAjlpCt3WOO707jglAA)

Comment: Nice, you can tell that there's a canonical way to do things when I was typing up an answer with verbatim same names.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I should have provided my real-life usage though, seems like it's enough for it. I have nullable/optional properties, which break `extends object`. I will update my post, sorry.

Might just need to add `NonNullable`?

Comment: @Tsury then you can just use `object | null`.

Comment: I ended up using `NonNullable<T[key]> extends object`, thank you so much for the fast answer.